# Interval arithmetics and complex numbers

Tags: complex, intervals

I am trying to do some simple calculations for a computer assisted proof and since they are not too demanding I thought of using Mathematica.

I seems that Mathematica is great for interval arithmetics with real number but doesn't know what to do with complex.

So when I define

```
t = 10 + I
```

then I get that 1/t is

```
10/101 - I/101
```

but if I set

```
t = Interval[N[10, 5]] + I Interval[N[1, 5]]
```

then I get that 1/t is

```
1/(I Interval[{1.000, 1.0000}] + Interval[{10.00, 10.000}])
```

and Mathematica doesn't want to simplify it any further. This of course cause my computer to crash if I try to any computation.

Is there a way to do this properly or I need to do this in some other language?

Comment: Disk arithmetic (the most natural extension of interval arithmetic to complex numbers) is not implemented in *Mathematica*, IIRC.

Comment: Why do you get a computer crash? What further computations might be the cause?

Comment: My computations involve series so I tried initially without checking the behaviour and it ate up all my memory.

Comment: It seems you should try working with geometric regions.. aside to the question, *low* precision numbers in mathematica are much slower and use much more memory than machine precision, so there is hardly a reason for `N[..,5]`

Comment: @george2079 this was just to check the behaviour. I generally use 200 digits of precision.

Comment: I stopped trying and instead I used Julia Language to do it. There is a nice library for high precision numerics